# Efficient algorithm for finding pairs of nearby, parallel streets in a map

Tags: python, algorithm, openstreetmap

I am working on a Python program that processes map data from Openstreetmap, and I need to be able to identify pairs of streets (ways) that are close to each other and parallel. Right now, the basic algorithm I'm using is quite inefficient:

1. Put all of the streets (Street objects) into a large list
2. Find every possible pair of two streets in the list using nested `for` loops; for each pair, draw a rectangle around the two streets and calculate the angle at which each street is oriented.
3. If the rectangles overlap, the overlapping area is big enough, and the angles are similar, the two streets in the pair are considered parallel and close to each other.

This works well for small maps but with large maps, the biggest problem obviously is that there would be a huge number of pairs to iterate through since there could be thousands of streets in a city. I want to be able to run the program on a large area (like a city) without having to split the area into smaller pieces.

One idea I'm thinking of is sorting the list of streets by latitude or longitude, and only comparing pairs of streets that are within, say, 50 positions away from each other in the list. It would probably be more efficient but it still doesn't seem very elegant; is there any better way?

Each Street is composed of Node objects, and I can easily retrieve both the Node objects and the lat/long position of each Node. I can also easily retrieve the angle at which a street is oriented.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Streets which are parallel in regarding of their start and end node only have the same angle on average, but will most likely not be parallel. Are you looking for parallel street-sections? Or maybe streets that share a node and run in the same direction? Your problem is well described, but it doesn't seem like the actual problem you want to solve?

Answer (score 3):

I think the first thing to do is to sort all the streets by angle, thus getting all parallel streets close to each other.

Then, assume for a start that you can identify the angle *exactly* and that you need pairs of streets that have *exactly* the same angle. (This is not a real case both due to floating point precision and due to the fact that needed streets might be non exactly parallel in the data, but let's forget about this for a time.)

Then all the sorted streets can be separated into groups of the same direction. Within each such group there exist a natural order defined as follows. Consider another line perpendicular to all the streets with the same direction. For any such street, consider the intersection point with that perpendicular line, and sort all these streets by this intersection point (I assume all the streets to be infinitively long).

This sorting can be easily done without any intersection, you need just calculate for each street the distance from origin (or any other fixed point) to that street line and sort streets by this distance. (If you have a street defined by a standard straight line equation `Ax+By+C=0`, then this distance from origin is `C/sqrt(A*A+B*B)`.)

Now you have all the needed parallel close streets very close to each other in this sort order. If all the streets were infinitively long, then such closest pairs would always go one after the other; with finite length of streets there might be additional streets in between, but I think that on any real data there will be very few of them. So you can just take some threshold of distance difference and check all pairs that fall within it.

Now let's remember that the angles are not defined precisely. I can suggest then the following approach. Maintain a binary search tree (something like C++'s `std::map`) for streets, the search key will be the distance from the origin to the street line. Go along the streets in the order as they are sorted by the angle. In the tree we will keep all the streets for which the angles differ by less then some threshold. Thus at each time for each street in the tree its neighbours in the tree will have both angles different by less then threshold, and distances from origin different by less then some threshold. So, for each street, do the following:

- Add this street to the tree
- For all the streets that are in the tree, but have their angle too different from the angle of current street, remove these streets from the tree
- Now process the added street: look at all the streets in the tree that has the search key (distance from origin) within the required threshold, and check the pair (added street, another street).

The first point is `O(log N)`, the second is `O(log N)` per deleted street if you just keep another pointer running along the sorted angles array pointing to the streets to be deleted, and the third is `O(log N)` per neighbour street considered.

A very rough pseudocode:

```
sort lines by angle
r = 0 // the street to be deleted from the tree
for l=0..n-1
    tree.add(street[l])
    while street[r].angle<streel[l].angle-angle_threshold
        tree.remove(street[r])
    other_street=tree.prev(street[l])
    while other_street.dist>street[l].dist-dist_threshold
        process(street[l], other_street)
        other_street = tree.prev(other_street)
    other_street=tree.next(street[l])
    while other_street.dist<street[l].dist+dist_threshold
        process(street[l], other_street)
        other_street = tree.next(other_street)
```

Here `tree.prev` finds the previous street in the tree, i.e. the street with maximal distance that is less then the distance for given street, and `tree.next` similarly finds the next street. Both operations can be done in `O(log N)`.

This does not "loop" the array, i.e. does not consider pairs of streets where one is located at very end of sorted array and the other at very beginning, but this is simple to fix.

Answer (score 3):

Your idea of processing the segments in bins is not bad. You do need to think through what happens to road segments that traverse bin boundaries.

Another idea is to Hough transform all the road segments. The infinite line that each segment lies on corresponds to a point in 2d Hough space: the polar angle of the line is one axis and the distance to the origin of the line's nearest point is the other.  The transformation from two points on a line to a Hough point is simple algebra.

Now you can detect nearly co-linear road segments by using a closest point pair algorithm. Happily this can be done in O(n log n) expected time. E.g. using a k-d tree. Insert all the points in the tree. Use the standard k-d tree algorithm to find each point's nearest neighbor. Sort the pair distances and take a prefix of the result as pairs to consider, stopping where the pairs are too far apart to meet your criterion of "nearby and parallel".  There are O(n) of such nearest neighbor pairs.

All that's left is to filter out segment pairs that - though nearly co-linear - don't overlap. These segments lie on or near different parts of the same infinite line, but they're not of interest. This is just a little more algebra.

There are reasonably good Wikipedia articles on all of the algorithms mentioned here. Look them up if they're not familiar.

Comment: I really like the idea but one issue I'm encountering is that it's finding pairs that are parallel, but not quite as close together as I want. What's the best way to "calibrate" it so that it gives more priority to distance between the streets and less priority to angle? I tried re-positioning the origin and that seemed to help somewhat but it's still not quite right.

Comment: You get to set the relative priority by scaling one axis of Hough space with respect to the other. Just multiply the distance value you're getting from the transform by some W>1. This is the relative weight of distance vs. angle. Then adjust the threshold of what's close downward.